# How do I get a wavy bold I for the identity matrix?

Tags: matrices, bold

How do I get a wavy bold letter ***I*** for the identity matrix?

```
$\mathcal{I}$
```

can give things like:

[image]

which don't immediately to me look like a capital I for the identity matrix.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you thinking of a calligraphic uppercase letter "I"? If so, you may want to start with `$\mathcal{I}$`. For many further possiblities, check out the [detexify site](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) and the [user guide](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/doc/mathalfa.pdf) of the `mathalfa` package.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mico's comment suggests, using `mathalfa` package gives you more options and these commands:

```
\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalfa}
...
$\mathcal{I}$
```

give

[image: mathalfa cm letter I]

or

```
\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalfa}
...
$\mathbcal{I}$
```

gives

[image]

which is much nicer - bold, wavy, and readable. See [`mathalfa` options](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/doc/mathalfa.pdf) for more info.